# cant load page by redirect

Tags: url, redirect

redirect(url_for) not working with me..i should enter title and content then the shown page for these info should shown up to me but its not , no errors its just not coming.. i dont know why ?

this is my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template ,request, redirect , url_for

app=Flask(__name__)
blog={
    'name':'My Nice Blog',
    'posts': {}
}
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def post(post_id):
        post=blog['posts'].get(post_id) #Nnon if not found
        if not post:
            return render_template('404.J2',message=f'A post no# {post_id} Not Exist')
        return render_template('post.J2',post=post)


@app.route('/post/create',methods=['GET','Post'])
def create():
    if request.method=='Post':
        title=request.form.get("Title")
        Content=request.form.get("content")
        post_id=len(blog['posts'])
        blog['posts'][post_id]={'post_id':post_id,'Title':title,'content':Content}
        **return redirect(url_for('post',post_id=post_id))**
    return render_template('create.html')
```

every thing is work just this line:

```
return redirect(url_for('post',post_id=post_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (note that POST is in all caps) and make sure you do are doing a POST to the route's endpoint

`methods=['GET','POST']`

and

`if request.method=='POST':`

Comment: i am sure that all in capital letters but still not work ,, when i print request.method this is shown up to me in terminal:* Serving Flask app 'second' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://.../ (Press CTRL+C to quit)